# Why Redshift wants me to have all the non-aggregated columns in GROUP clause?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Placing all non-aggregated columns in GROUP clause can result in different datasets.For eg:

Table `sample`:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

`SELECT sum(x),y,z  FROM sample group by z` results in:

```
+--------+---+---+
| sum(x) | y | z |
+--------+---+---+
|     11 | 3 | 1 |
+--------+---+---+
```

whereas,
`SELECT sum(x),y,z  FROM sample group by y,z` results in:

```
+--------+---+---+
| sum(x) | y | z |
+--------+---+---+
|      6 | 2 | 1 |
|      5 | 3 | 1 |
+--------+---+---+
```

Why, then, I am required to have all non-aggregated columns in GROUP clause in Redshift?

P.S. : Example query run on mySQL.

Comment: this is bad practice and mysql is non standard in this respect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT
    SUM(x),   -- sum all records by x in a z group
    y,        -- but what do you want to do here?
    z         -- select the z group
FROM sample
GROUP BY z
```

will not even run on most SQL databases, and I am surprised that it runs on Redshift.  The problem here is that you are aggregating by `z` but then also selecting `y`.  It is not clear *which* `y` value you want to select for each group of `z` records.  The way a database gets around this problem is by requiring every column selected to either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or to be inside an aggregate function such as `MAX` or `SUM`.  Under these assumptions, the value returned for each entry in the select statement is deterministic.

Comment: He is running it on MySQL; his complaint is that Redshift requires columns that aren't aggregated to be in the group by.